# LARAVEL 4: share data between Route::filter and Route::get

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i have somthing like this:

```
Route::get('dashboard/objects/add', array('before'=>'objectadd', function(){
   return $filter_data;
});

Route::filter('objectadd', function(){
   $filter_data = 'Some data';
});
```

How i can return $filter_data to dashboard/objects/add?

Comment: If you need it in the View then you can use `View::share` or you can use Session::put('key','value')

Comment: Thanks, i needed this View::share :)

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation would be to use a cache:

```
Route::get('dashboard/objects/add', array('before'=>'objectadd', function(){
   return Cache::get('objectadd');
});

Route::filter('objectadd', function(){
   $filter_data = 'Some data';
   Cache::forever('objectadd', $filter_data);
});
```

Though why bother to use a filter if you're just gonna use it this way?